# How to wait for completion of multi-threaded publish-subscribe-channel

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration project where I want to process a message concurrently through multiple actions. So I have set up a `publish-subscribe-channel` with a `task-executor`. However I want to wait for all processing to complete before moving on. How would I do this?

```
<publish-subscribe-channel id="myPubSub" task-executor="my10ThreadPool"/>

<channel id="myOutputChannel"/>

<service-activator input-channel="myPubSub" output-channel="myOutputChannel"
         ref="beanA" method="blah"/>
<service-activator input-channel="myPubSub" output-channel="myOutputChannel"
         ref="beanB" method="blah"/>

<service-activator id="afterThreadingProcessor" input-channel="myOutputChannel" .../>
```

So in the above case, I want my `afterThreadingProcessor` to be invoked only once after both `beanA` and `beanB` have completed their work. However, in the above `afterThreadingProcessor` will be invoked twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add `apply-sequence="true"` to the pub-sub channel (this adds default correlation data to the messages, including `correlationId`, `sequenceSize`, and `sequenceNumber` and allows default strategies to be used on downstream components).
2. Add an `<aggregator/>` before `afterThreadingProcessor` and route the output from the two `<service-activator/>`s to it.
3. Add a `<splitter/>` after the aggregator - the default splitter will split the collection made by the aggregator into two messages.

`afterThreadingProcessor` will be invoked once for each message on the second thread that completes its work.

You can make the configuration easier by using a chain...

```
<chain input-channel="myOutputChannel">
    <aggregator />
    <splitter />
    <service-activator id="afterThreadingProcessor" input-channel="myOutputChannel" .../>
</chain>
```

To make a single call to the final service, just change your service to take a `Collection<?>` instead of adding the splitter.

EDIT:

In order to do what you want in comment #3 (run the final service on the original thread), something this should work...

```
<int:channel id="foo" />
<int:service-activator ref="twoServicesGateway" input-channel="foo"
      output-channel="myOutputChannel" />

<int:gateway id="twoServicesGateway" default-request-channel="myPubSub"/>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="myPubSub" task-executor="my10ThreadPool"
            apply-sequence="true"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="myPubSub" output-channel="aggregatorChannel"
         ref="beanA" method="blah"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="myPubSub" output-channel="aggregatorChannel"
         ref="beanB" method="blah"/>
    <int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatorChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="afterThreadingProcessor" input-channel="myOutputChannel" .../>
```

In this case, the gateway encapsulates the two other services and the aggregator; the default `service-interface` is a simple `RequestReplyExchanger`. The calling thread will wait for the output. Since the aggregator has no `output-channel` the framework will send the reply to the gateway, and the waiting thread will receive it, return to the `<service-activator/>` and the result will then be sent to the final service.

You would probably want to put a `reply-timeout` on the gateway because, by default, it will wait indefinitely and, if one of the services returns a null, no agreggated response will ever be received.

Note that I indented the gateway flow just to show it runs from the gateway, they are NOT child elements of the gateway.

Comment: Will this work when in the middle of a split / aggregate pair? I believe I recall that SI can handle multiple levels of split / aggregate.

Comment: So this works well with one issue. With this solution it is a random thread from the pub-sub executor on which the service-activator is invoked. Is there a way to have the original thread which submitted to the pub-sub wait for completions and have it be the thread that continues processing?

Comment: Reply to first comment - yes, items that add/remove sequence details now push/pop them in the headers, so nested components work. (It was not supported in very early versions of SI). Let me think about your last comment.

Comment: I edited my response to show one way to call the final service on the original thread.

Comment: Wow~ this is the one I really need. But how can I add the transaction commit logic right after all subscribers finish the tasks?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but you cannot have multiple threads participate in the same transaction.

Comment: Is it possible to use scatter-gather to achieve same requirement of concurrent message processing?

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of behavior can now be achieved using a more cleaner approach introduced in ***Spring Integration 4.1.0*** as an implementation of EIP ***Scatter-Gather*** pattern.

Checkout Scatter-Gather example gist:
https://gist.github.com/noorulhaq/b13a19b9054941985109